# How do I provide a public key to a new user without granting them root access?

Tags: linux, users, user-accounts

I have a linux server and have created a new user with `useradd`.  However, for that user to log in, they need an public key.  I have my own public key, but it lets me log in as root, so I assume it would let them do the same.

How do I provide the new user with the proper keys while preventing them from logging in as root?

Answer (score 2):

Each user must create his own key pair (public + private) then the user keep the private key and give the public key to sysadmin.

The sysadmin (you) import the user public key into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.